# horizontal slide in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that this is a frequent question but I can't find an answer that matches my requirements.

In short, I want to horizontal slide a box from the right-side (insivisible) part of the screen to the left and then from the left back to the right.

The html/css/js below demonstrates what I want:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#box-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80em;
  background-color: #f00;
}
#box-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: #0f0;
}
#viewport {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100em;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="viewport">
  <div id="container">
    <div style="position: relative">
      <div id="box-1">
      </div>
      <div id="box-2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#box-1").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().animate({left: "-100%"});
});
$("#box-2").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().animate({left: "0"});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, everything might seem fine except for two important things:

- I do not want to specify a height for the outer viewport. I would like this viewport to adopt automatically the height of the highest item in the container
- this code does not do what I want if you scroll down at the bottom of the page when the red box is visible and click on it: the green box comes within the viewport but it is scrolled at the bottom.  I would like the green box to come in view directly. As a bonus, it would be nice if once the green box is in view, if I click on it, the red box came back in view at its previous scroll position.

Of course, this example has lots of other limitations (the default animation function provided by jquery sucks, etc...) but I believe I can fix them later.

Given the limitations of the solution I have posted here, I suspect that I did not chose the right approach but I have no idea on where I should start.

Comment: I put your example into a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Av7P3/, I've added that viewport will get the height of the highest element, regarding the 2nd issue, can you clarify? you want the green box to always show at the top no matter how far you scroll down?

Comment: You may also like this answer about [horizontal page sliding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414642/responsive-horizontal-page-sliding-navigation/24465646#24465646)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scroll to the top of the div when you click on the box.
Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
    var vheight = Math.max($("#box-1").height(), $("#box-2").height());
    $("#viewport").height(vheight)
});
$("#box-1").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().animate({left: "-100%"});
    $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#box-1").offset().top
    });
});
$("#box-2").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().animate({left: "0"});
    $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#box-2").offset().top
    });
});
```

I also updated the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Av7P3/1/

Comment: Ok, this is not exactly what I had in mind but it did put me on the right track. Thanks !